# Is there a EOS pegged token for Bitcoin or Ethereum or Monero?

Tags: ethereum, bitcoin, monero

Is there a pegged token like USDT for US dollars, but for bitcoin, ethereum, or monero out yet on EOS?

Comment: nope, but i don't think this exists on any blockchain today?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dice [announced in December](https://medium.com/@dice1/betdice-announcements-5-dec-620c8c881722) that they would create pegged EOS tokens for Bitcoin, Ethereum, and USDT.

In their announcement, they said:

> The user deposits the corresponding currency into a specific gateway
>   address. They will be issued an equal amount of the EOS-based coin.
>   For example, a BTC deposit will give the same number of EOSBTC coins
>   on EOS. The user can redeem their EOSBTC for BTC at any time. The cold
>   wallet address will be publicized and managed by multi-sign, and the
>   balance of the hot and cold wallet will be updated in real time on the
>   website of our partner. The total balance of these two parts is equal
>   to the circulation of BTC on EOS.